# Warning: Illegal string offset 'ID' in C:\xampp\htdocs\SwaziTour\MyDashboard.php on line 637

Tags: php, mysql

I got above Error from below For Loop;

```
while($Row=mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
    $result_list[] = $Row;

}
foreach((array)$result_list as $Row) {
    $ID=$Row['ID'];
    $Name=$Row['name'];
    $has_acco = $Row['Accomodation'];
}
```

Comment: `$result_list` is already __array__, there's no need to cast it to `array`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: This is quite straightforward, the lines of your array don't have `ID`. What does your array look like ?

Comment: Please, post `print_r(result_list)`, I think your array don't have `ID`

Answer (score 0):

try code this way

```
while($Row=mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
    $ID=$Row['ID'];
    $Name=$Row['name'];
    $has_acco = $Row['Accomodation'];
}
```

no need extra `for loop`

Comment: I am not only displaying the values but I am reusing them, there are operations I didn't show in the For loop, I need the For loop

Comment: so `print_r($result_list)` before for loop and see what the value?